# Getting 6 errors when compiling the wrapper module output by SWIG?

Tags: c, perl, swig

[`gcc -fpic -c gd_wrap.c -Dbool=char -I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE`](http://www.swig.org/papers/Perl98/swigperl.htm):

```
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/op.h:499,
                 from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:2754,
                 from gd_wrap.c:731:
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/reentr.h:612: error: field ‘_crypt_struct’ has incomplete type
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:3950,
                 from gd_wrap.c:731:
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:297: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘off64_t’
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:299: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_do_sysseek’
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:300: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_do_tell’
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:2009: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before Perl_PerlIO_tell’
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:2010: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘off64_t’
```

Anyone familiar with this error?

I'm on Centos `5.5`  and perl version is `5.8.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a well known bug (simply search on google for keywords Perl_do_sysseek and swig.

There are two solutions I have found in the past.

The first is really dirty (and I despise it) but works at 100%. It consist in adding at the top of "proto.h" file these lines:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef __off64_t off64_t;
```

The second system it's cleaner then the first. You should upgrade swig to version 2.0 and retry. If it doesn't work you can try upgrading perl to version 5.10.0.

Comment: what about `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/reentr.h:612: error: field ‘_crypt_struct’ has incomplete type`?

Comment: ah, for this, just define "_GNU_SOURCE" putting in compile line  "-D_GNU_SOURCE"

Comment: just curious,how can you remember all this?

Comment: I'm working in a company that writes all its code in languages (C++, java, php, python, perl and ruby) and I live writing code in C++ and translating it in all languages using SWIG, boost.python, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is my makefile that solves the problem for me.

all :  test

## -isystem /usr/local/include

CFLAGS= -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

icinga-core-wrap-perl.c : icinga-core.i 
    swig -perl -outcurrentdir   -o icinga-core-wrap-perl.c  -oh icinga-core-wrap-perl.h icinga-core.i

icinga-core-wrap-perl.o : icinga-core-wrap-perl.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -I../include icinga-core-wrap-perl.c -I/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/ -o icinga-core-wrap-perl.o

test : icinga-core-wrap-perl.o 
    echo todo

https://gitorious.org/icinga/icinga-core/commit/5c19af4baf01b6741bdef782a33339da0e403de6